# How do I change the starting scene (GameScene)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have searched for a few hours now with no avail. Perhaps I am just over looking a simple solution, but I would like to know how and where to alter the scene that auto starts up when you launch your app. To make a main menu or credits scene in my project.

Comment: For now I will leave this open. I am going to just make a new scene and put my code in there and make my Game Scene into a menu. If someone down the line gets this and has a an answer I will check mark.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the view controller.m class and change it there where the game scene is declared and defined. Just change it to the name of your MenuScene class.
Hope it helps!

Comment: I changed the "let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene" to let scene = MenuScene.unarchiveFromFile("MenuScene") as? MenuScene" and invoked it with "skView.presentScene(scene)" but it still loads the "GameScene"